# android: ContentResolver works on 4.0 but not on 2.3

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

In the contacts provider I'm building I want to create contacts group and then add the contacts to that group. This is my code for creating new group if one does not exist:

```
if (groupId == 0) {
        // Sample group doesn't exist yet, so create it
        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        contentValues.put(Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        contentValues.put(Groups.TITLE, Constants.GROUP_NAME);
        contentValues.put(Groups.GROUP_IS_READ_ONLY, true);

        final Uri newGroupUri = resolver.insert(Groups.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        Log.d(TAG, newGroupUri.toString());
        groupId = ContentUris.parseId(newGroupUri);
    }
```

When I run this on android 4.0 or 4.1 it works, but when I run this on 2.3 `newGroupUri` is null. What is the problem with 2.3. I tried it both on emulator and phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contentValues.put(Groups.GROUP_IS_READ_ONLY, true); is only available since api 11